# 'git push heroku main' command looping install process

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

I'm trying to deploy to Heroku from my projects root folder. Although the build seems to repeat the same process without end.

As below

```
remote:        > mygym-gym@1.0.0 install
remote:        > cd server && npm install && cd ../client && npm install
remote:
remote:        
remote:        added 301 packages, and audited 302 packages in 4s
remote:
remote:        16 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        > mygym-gym@1.0.0 install
remote:        > cd server && npm install && cd ../client && npm install
remote:
remote:        
remote:        up to date, audited 302 packages in 820ms
remote:
remote:        16 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
```

Scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "develop": "concurrently \"cd server && npm run watch\" \"cd client && npm start\"",
    "install": "cd server && npm install && cd ../client && npm install",
    "seed": "cd server && npm run seed",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0"
  }
```

server

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "watch": "nodemon server.js",
    "seed": "node config/seeds.js"
  },
```

client

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Does anybody have any idea what might cause this?
I've run similar applications and this is the first time I've encountered this error.

Comment: That's normal, expected behavior. You haven't shown anything unusual. The app is built on every git commit. And in a node app the app is built with npm install. You've shown a partial log of that and there is nothing unusual there.

Comment: @TinNguyen, I think OP is showing that their build command is running multiple times during a single deployment: `cd server && npm install && cd ../client && npm install` shows up twice here.

Comment: OP, please [edit]  your `server/package.json` and `client/package.json` files into your question (at least their scripts).

Comment: Usually, install only runs once. It's run over 100 times? Usually it runs once and then runs the build process